# How to use the 'find' and 'substr' functions with Vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm making a program that searches a string vector for first words of sentences. It stores first words in a new vector for later use. In the code, allWords is the resulting vector after reading a file.

allWords contents:

```
0000000    f   i   r   s   t       l   i   n   e       i   s       h   e
0000020    r   e   .  \n   s   e   c   o   n   d       l   i   n   e    
0000040    i   s       h   e   r   e       a   f   t   e   r       t   h
0000060    e       f   i   r   s   t   ?  \n   t   h   i   r   d       l
0000100    i   n   e       c   o   m   e   s       n   e   x   t   !    
0000120   \n   f   o   u   r   t   h       l   i   n   e       t   h   e
0000140    n       t   h   e  \n   .   .   .   f   i   f   t   h       i
0000160    s       t   h   e       l   i   n   e       b   e   f   o   r
0000200    e       t   h   e       s   i   x   t   h  \n   s   i   x   t
0000220    h       i   s       t   h   e       l   a   s   t       o   n
```

Then my code to get the first word.

```
string firstWord = allWords.substr(0, allWords.find(' '));
someVector.push_back(firstWord);
```

Here, I am trying to get the very first word of the first sentence, but run into the errors:

‘class std::vector >’ **has no member named ‘find’**

‘class std::vector >’ **has no member named ‘substr’**

I looked up a lot of code and other people seem to be able to use at least 'find' with vectors. Any suggestions on how to fix this without creating my own find and substr functions?

Comment: `std::vector` does not have a `find` member. You may be thinking of the generic [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm that can be applied to any kind of container.

Comment: also `std::vector` has no `substr` (it is not a string), but you can easily create a subvector by calling the constructor that takes a start and begin iterator

Comment: anyhow, to make the question answerable please include a [mcve]. What is `allWords` exactly? a `std::vector<char>` perhaps?

Comment: If vector did have a `substr` method then the result would be another vector, not a string as you have it. I think you're a little confused about types.

Comment: Do you have a `std::vector<std::string>>` with contents like `{ "Some words", "as elements of", "a string vector" }`, and you are looking to extract the first word from each string, i.e. `{ "Some", "as", "a" }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a loop to traverse through the vector. Within the loop body, you can operate on the current string. Those operations will be repeated for each string within the vector if you traverse through the entire vector. You can use the member functions `find` and `substr` of the string.